# Open link in background when anchor's attribute "href" contains javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I support web enterprise-level application with some legacy parts, where some windows are opened by using window.open command inside of anchor's href attribute. (e.g.  ... function MyFunction(url, id) { window.open(url, id) ...)

Now I have to open link in the background tab by pressing ctrl + click (or middle click), but for IE (9, 10, 11) it always becomes focused. Same works fine in chrome.

Here is a link where it can be tested:

```
<a href="javascript:OpenNewTab('http://google.com', 1)"> Open google tab </a>
```

```js
OpenNewTab = function(url, id){
    window.open(url, id);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hj3gud9j/

Are there any ways to open those new tabs in the background (only when ctrl is pressed)?

P.S. I know that it would be better to provide real url inside of href attribute, but unfortunatelly I don't have such options, due to application specific.

Thank you in advace for your help!

Comment: Can you use event listeners instead of href attribute?

Comment: It's better to be avoided, since it'll require a lot of changes across application and might have snowball effect. Best option whould be somehow change internals of handler. Or at least find some official proof that this is normal behaviour for IE

Comment: I just tested IE's behaviour and when you CTRL+click or middleclick the tab gets opened en focused immediately. But the solution I was thinking about does not need alot of changes across the application, it's just a small script that runs on every page with anchors on them.

Comment: Only event handlers can detect keys, that's it..

Comment: Hey A1rPun, what script do you mean? Can you please show it in jsfiddle?

Comment: Hey Teemu, have you ever seen official proof that IE works in that way only? Still chrome is able to identify what kind of click was done and behaves accordingly even for links with javascript inside of href attribute

Comment: Well, you can open an official IE, then open Internet Options, click Tabs button. There you'll find an option, if a newly opened tab should be focused or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a piece of javascript everytime the page loads, or every time you request a page (single-page app).

This code is not fully functional but I hope you catch my drift :)

```
function createListener(url){
    return function(event){
        if(event.ctrlKey){
            console.log(url); //Here you can do anything you want with the url
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}

function runOnce(){
    var allAnchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var i = allAnchors.length; i--;){
        var a = allAnchors[i],
            href = a.getAttribute('href'),
            split = href.split('('),
            url = split[1].split(',')[0];
        a.href = '#';
        a.addEventListener('click', createListener(url));
    }
}
runOnce();
```

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3v6w0fL/)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, A1rPun! I got your point, I was also thinking about something similar, but those kind of workarounds we'd prefer to avoid (again due to application specific). It would be better If we able to fix that just inside of function handler (if possible) or just provide proof, that this is normal IE behaviour for links with js in href.